# Define age in django template using actual datatime and birthday with datafield

Tags: python, django, datafield

i'm begginer at django and trying to display age for every user in my base of users.

Here's my code:

models.py:

```
class Cv(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    telephone = models.IntegerField()
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
    skills = models.TextField(null=True)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    interests = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)




    def zapisz(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.surname
```

template.html:

```
{% block base %}
<div class="vvv">
    <h2>Base of users</h2><hr>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nr.</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Specialization</th>     
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          {% for cv in cvs %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{forloop.counter}}.</td>
                <td><a href="{% url "proj.views.cv_detail" pk=cv.pk %}">{{cv.name}} {{cv.surname}}</a></td>
                <td>{{cv.specialization}}</td>      
                <td>{{ cv.age }} </td>
                <td>{{cv.email}}</td>
              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
    </table><br>


</div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def base_cv(request):

    cvs = Cv.objects.filter()

    for cv in cvs:

        def calculate_age(self):
            import datetime
            return int((datetime.datetime.now() - cv.birth_date).days / 365.25  )

        age = property(calculate_age)

    con = {

    'cvs': cvs,
    'age': age,
    }

    return render(request, 'base_cv.html', con)
```

And don't know why the fields after rendering and displaying, are empty.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you adding that property dynamically, rather than just defining it on the Cv class itself?

Comment: Also, why do you have `cvs = Cv.objects.filter()`?

Comment: Becouse i need to have all cvs on the page

Comment: Then do `cvs = Cv.objects.all()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`calculate_age` should be a function on the model.  You can use the `@property` decorator described [here](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) like:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Cv(models.Model):

    ...

    @property
    def age(self):
        return int((datetime.now().date() - self.birth_date).days / 365.25)
```

Then your view can simply be:

```
@login_required
def base_cv(request):
    con = {'cvs': Cv.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'base_cv.html', con)
```

[all](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/) is preferred over `filter` when you want all of the models.

Comment: Ok, i did like u said. And what now? How to display it instead cv.age or cv.birth_date ?

Comment: is `<td>{{ cv.age }} </td>` in your template not displaying the correct age?

Comment: And what do you mean by "How to display it instead of..."  Display what exactly?

Comment: no, it's empty still. I want to display the actual age of the user, using this function.

Comment: Is `<td>{{cv.email}}</td>` displaying the correct email?

Comment: Ah, I'll update my code.  Try `int((datetime.datetime.now().date() - self.birth_date).days / 365.25  )`